# MVVM: Populate a view (with listbox) when an item from another view (with listbox) is selected

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a list of Topics, and for each topic there are some Examples. What I want to be able to do is that when a topic is selected then I will populate another view with all Examples for that selected topic. I'm still learning MVVM so not sure how to implement such.

EDIT:
What I am attempting to do is to have two separate views (1 for the topics and 1 for the examples), and when an a topic is selected then I will 'dynamically' populate the collection of the examples and show them in the listbox of the examples' view.

This is what I have so far, my idea is to pass the ViewModel of example to the TopicViewModel, but I am unsure how to do it if both views are set in the XAML of the main window:

```
public TopicViewModel SelectedTopic
{
    get { return _selectedTopic; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTopic = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTopic");

        //refresh list of exercises
        if (_exampleViewModel != null)
        {
            _exampleViewModel.RefreshExercises(_selectedTopic.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have something like this:

```
class Topic
{
    public ObservableCollection<Example> Examples { get; private set; }
}
```

and in your ViewModel somewhere this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Topic> Topics { get; private set; }
```

Then your binding in the Topics ListBox might look like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="topicsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Topics}" />
```

You could then bind to the `Examples` of this ListBox's selected item like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="examplesListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Examples, ElementName=topicsListBox}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, trying to decipher your example and apply it in my case. Can I not pass an ExampleViewModel to the ExampleView instead and it should be reflected in the listbox?

Comment: @RodelioMartinezRodriguez I thought you want to display a *Collection* of ExampleViewModels in the listbox? I guess you could set the SelectedItem (of type Topic) as DataContext on the other view though and then just set the ListBox's ItemsSource to {Binding Examples}

Comment: In my ExamplesViewModel there is already a ObservableCollection of Examples model that can be bound to a listbox. There is just one ExamplesViewModel for every ExampleView.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how much data you need to work with, IMHO the easiest way is this.

firstly use ObservableCollection for all your lists

Have a main parent view model that contains the list of topic view models
where each topic view model contains a list of examples

in the parent view model have a property that will hold the currently selected topic.

in your view you can use 2 listboxes.  one bound to the list of topics.  the other bound to the selected topics examples list.

there are a heap of examples out on the web with this stuff.
This stackoverflow question shows how to bind to the list and the selected item
[MVVM: Binding to ListBox.SelectedItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384369/mvvm-binding-to-listbox-selecteditem)

Comment: Edited my question to show some code, didn't know I cannot post code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly

you have one Window with 2x View's where each View has here own ViewModel, right so far?

so you should probably us a Mediator resp. a eventaggregation

now you can subscribe  from one ViewModel and publish from the other one

to get an Mediator resp. a Eventaggregation

you can use existent Frameworks like

- [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)
- [caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/)
- and many more

or create it on your own

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Will try to look into those you have recommended, thanks!

Comment: Looks like I can try the method presented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412405/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pass-data-between-view-models

Comment: @RodelioMartinezRodriguez yes something like that his `ViewModel1`would be your `ParentViewModel`