# MVVM: Convert code-behind to XAML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, mvvm

I've got an AllTopicsViewModel and its got a property ExerciseVM which is an AllExerciseViewModel, since I want to be able to refresh the AllExerciseViewModel of an ExerciseView so I am doing it like this (not even sure if it violates MVVM, pls. tell me). Well, I want to convert the 2 lines following the InitializeComponent to XAML but not sure how, can anyone help me out?

```
  public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AllTopicsViewModel vm = (AllTopicsViewModel)topicsView.DataContext;
        vm.ExerciseVM = (AllExercisesViewModel)exercisesView.DataContext;

    }
```

Comment: What is the bigger picture? vm is local variable. What are you planning to do with it?

Comment: Its related to the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536205/mvvm-populate-a-view-with-listbox-when-an-item-from-another-view-with-listbo

The AllTopicsViewModel is the ModelView of topicsView and I am just referencing it and trying to set its ExerciseVM property with the ViewModel (AllExercisesViewModel) of exerciseView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a misconception, according to the idea of MVVM.

Ideally, your View's codebehind (view.xaml.cs) contains nothing more than the auto generated code. Your view only accesses the ViewModel via WPF's data binding mechanisms. Because data binding via WPF is a loose coupling between the binding view and the bound-to ViewModel, you achieve the seperation that drives people to use MVVM.

You are retrieving the ViewModel in the Views codebehind from your control's DataContexts. With this, you create a strong reference between View and ViewModel. So, to help you with your question: You should think about what you are trying to to do with your ViewModel in the View's codebehind and how you can do it differently, either in the view's XAML or in the ViewModel's code itself.

If you like, post the complete `MainWindow()` class for some advice...

EDIT:

Ok, so its just about setting the child ViewModel on the parent ViewModel. The parent ViewModel `AllTopicsViewModel` should be responsible for setting its own `ExerciseVM` on initialization. This is not the View's job. the parent viewModel should assemble the data from one or more models and then create the child view models which the view consumes. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: Well, that basically is just the content of my MainWindow class so I am attempting to remove it and do the binding in XAML but I don't know how.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got the idea but how do I bind the ExerciseView to the ExerciseVM property of the AllTopicsViewModel in my MainWindow using XAML?

Comment: Sorted it. I think I had the wrong impression that the View should automatically set its ViewModel (in its own XAML), instead I binded the DataContext in the MainWindow and the views automatically found the viewmodels they should bound to. It worked. Thanks all!

Comment: @RodelioMartinezRodriguez: Perfect, good to hear that you solved it with a clean MVVM approach. It really is the hardest part when your starting with MVVM to understand how you wire everything up. Great that you made it.